# Magento Custom Tab Grid with Ajax Grids error

Tags: php, ajax, magento, grid

I want to add custom edit tabs for magento backend admin.
i have been following some tutorial, from :

- http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-grid-serializer-ajax-grids/
- http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid/

but I always have same result :
Fatal error: Call to a member function setSelectedCustomers() on boolean in controller.php

Is there something wrong? Help me to solve this problem, please. :)

**SOLVED**

- I forgot to inclue  layout in config.xml
- clear cache